# Risks of running selenium chrome driver in head-ded (normal) mode on a remote linux server?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver, remote-server

I'm trying to do a particular automation task using python selenium chrome driver. For whatever reason the .click() does not work when I use the web driver in headless mode. So, I dont mind using it in normal mode, but my script needs to run in a remote AWS server. I'm wondering if its safe to do so i.e., launch chrome window (not suppressing it with --headless option) in a remote linux kernel. I just need my code to get executed, I really dont care about seeing the steps in a browser live (whether hosted by my local or hosted by my server)- I just figured out that the script does not proceed past a crucial step in headless mode. And my script needs to necessarily run on the server. Is it risky to launch browser GUI on a remote linux server? Can this set-up work? How do I make this work?